# How to bulk import on new parse server?

Tags: android, parse-platform, parse-server

So when using parse's dashboard you could just drop a csv file to import rows for a class.

Is there a way to do this on the new parse server?

Comment: Checkout this issue over on github: https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-dashboard/issues/307

Comment: Awesome, thank you, exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to import csv data to your parse-server, you'll have to manually parse your csv files and use the Rest API to create the objects. I've set up a [simple tool](https://parboard.github.io/data-importer/) that automates the process.

Note that parse-server doesn't allow you to manually set object ids, so if you're importing data exported from parse all the new objects will have new object ids.